# Reviewing a penalty in the NFL

Tags: rules, american-football, officiating, nfl, video-review

The referees ruled that the Jets had too many defensive players on the field by a review in their game on December 23, 2018.

Can you review offside, holding, or any penalty for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Penalties are not reviewable, except for number of players on the field before the snap. See [the NFL rulebook](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2018-nfl-rulebook/#article-4.-non-reviewable-plays).